# How to make smooth brush strokes in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

**CURRENTLY**

I am drawing brush strokes in after effects that will be animated as arrows.

**ISSUE**

Every time I draw my brush strokes they come out jagged (not smooth).

[image: brush strokes aren't smooth]

Is there a way to make smooth brush strokes? or edit existing ones to make smooth?
I know that Illustrator has "Fidelity" option, but I cannot find something similar in After Effects. I couldn't find anything online to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw them as paths instead, using bezier curves.
Then add arrows to the paths using this:
https://kylasaurusrex.gumroad.com/l/LNSVU